# Can I upgrade existing standard service bus namespace to premium service bus

Tags: azureservicebus, servicebus

Can I upgrade existing standard service bus namespace to premium service bus.
Currently I'm using standard service bus but now I want to upgrade plan to premium service bus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot upgrade a Standard namespace to Premium w/o creating a new namespace.
There are good tips by the ASB team what to watch out for when moving from Standard to Premium in this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2016/07/28/tips-on-migrating-existing-solutions-to-premium-messaging/).

Comment: The title and author of the article are : "Tips On Migrating Existing Solutions To Premium Messaging" John Taubensee .  Dated July 28, 2016.  (Just in case the link dies in the future, future readers will have ~something to search on)

Answer (score 0):

[Update] now you are able to upgrade your service bus from Standard tier to Premium by following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-migrate-standard-premium).
Bear in mind this can be done from Portal, Powershel or Azure CLI.